# PHP My Admin : #2003 - Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-2003

I have Wamp Server 2.1 installed on my Windows XP system.
It was working fine yesterday but today when I started Wamp server and opened phpMyAdmin 
I got this error :

**MySQL said:**
**#2003 - Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)**

> When I open the MySql Consle I am able to login and run queries.

Please help me with this ASAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled Wamp and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it is not the right answer but i get this error when I installed some internet security software.Add exception for wamp

hope it helps